# Double integral $\int _0^1\int _0^{x^2}xye^{x^2+y^2}dydx$

Tags: integration

I'm stuck with this double integral.

$$\int _0^1\int _0^{x^2}xye^{x^2+y^2}dydx$$

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

I'm going to be very gratefull for any help, since it's a very important example for my exam.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Well, it seems like just noting
$$
e^{x^2+y^2} = e^{x^2} \cdot e^{y^2}
$$
makes this pretty trivial ...

Comment: I saw that as well

Comment: $$\int _0^1 xe^{x^2}\int _0^{x^2}ye^{y^2}dydx$$ but then when I have just the outer left, it's not that easy for me to solve it

Comment: $$\int _0^1xe^{x^2}(e^{x^4}-1)dx$$ I got to this point and I'm not able to find any way to solve it

Comment: Hint: try using a change of variables.

Comment: $$0,5\int _0^1e^u(e^{u^2}-1)du$$ and that's where I got stuck. what can I do then? thanks for trying to make me understand it

Comment: Hmm I thought a switch to polar coordinates would fix things up but it does not seem to achieve anything. I do not see how to solve this integral either for the moment, my apologies.

Comment: no worries, let's hope someone is gonna be ale to help me

Comment: You'll need [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html).

Answer (score 4):

First we integrate the inside part:
$$
\int^{1}_{0}\int^{x^2}_{0}xye^{x^2+y^2}dydx=\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{2}xe^{x^2}(e^{x^4}-1)dx
$$
Now changing variable $x^2=u$, we have:
$$
\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{2}xe^{x^2}(e^{x^4}-1)dx=\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{4}e^{u^2+u}du-\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{0}e^udu=\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{4}e^{u^2+u}du-\frac{1}{4}(e-1).
$$
Now we are going to perform the left over integral:
$$
\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{0}e^{u^2+u}du=\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{0}e^{\big(u+\frac{1}{2}\big)^2}e^{-\frac{1}{4}}du.
$$
Now let $u+\frac{1}{2}=z$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{1}{4}}\int^{3/2}_{1/2}e^{z^2}dz.
$$
Using
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\text{erfi}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{z^2}
$$
we have:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}e^{-\frac{1}{4}}\big(\text{erfi}\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)-\text{erfi}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)\big).
$$
All terms together:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}e^{-\frac{1}{4}}\big(\text{erfi}\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)-\text{erfi}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)\big)+\frac{1}{4}(1-e).
$$

Comment: [Confirmation by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint+_0%5E1%5Cint+_0%5E%7Bx%5E2%7Dxye%5E%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%7Ddydx)